# Merge pandas dataframe with overwrite of columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is the quickest way to merge to python data frames in this manner?
I have two data frames with similar structures (both have a primary key id and some value columns).
What I want to do is merge the two data frames based on id. Are there any ways do this based on pandas operations? How I've implemented it right now is as coded below:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,3,4], 'letter': ['A', 'C', 'D']})
a_dict =  {e[id]: e for e in a.to_dict('record')}
b_dict =  {e[id]: e for e in b.to_dict('record')}
c_dict = a_dict.copy()
c_dict.update(b_dict)
c = pd.DataFrame(list(c.values())
```

Here, c would be equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4], 'letter':['A','b', 'C', 'D']})

   id letter
0   1      A
1   2      b
2   3      C
3   4      D
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `combine_first`

If `'id'` is your primary key, then use it as your index.

```
b.set_index('id').combine_first(a.set_index('id')).reset_index()

   id letter
0   1      A
1   2      b
2   3      C
3   4      D
```

---

#### `merge` with `groupby`

```
a.merge(b, 'outer', 'id').groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).last()

   id letter
0   1      A
1   2      b
2   3      C
3   4      D
```

Comment: Very nice solution, very elegant. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

One way may be as following:

- append dataframe `a` to dataframe `b`
- drop duplicates based on `id`
- sort values on remaining by `id`
- reset index and drop older index

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
b = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,3,4], 'letter': ['A', 'C', 'D']})

c = b.append(a).drop_duplicates(subset='id').sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
c = pd.concat([a, b], axis=0).sort_values('letter').drop_duplicates('id', keep='first').sort_values('id')

c.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

print(c)

    id  letter
0   1   A
1   2   b
2   3   C
3   4   D
```